# jquery simple slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I am trying to make a simple jquery slideshow, but I am not able to.

I am using the following code but I just get the second image not the first.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#slides1").attr("src", "resources/images/slide_1.jpg");
         $("#slides1").fadeOut(1000);
         $("#slides1").delay(1000).attr("src", "resources/images/slide_2.jpg");
         $("#slides1").fadeIn(1000).delay(1000);
 }
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

## slides is am img tag with id="slides1"

I tried the following code but still does not work.

```
$("#slides1").delay(500).attr("src", "resources/images/slide_2.jpg").delay(1000).fadeOut(1000).delay(1000).attr("src", "resources/images/slide_1.jpg").fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: try chaining the events: $("#slides1").attr("src", "resources/images/slide_1.jpg").fadeOut(1000).delay(1000).attr("src", "resources/images/slide_2.jpg") etc. Since jQuery commands dont wait for each other.

Comment: tried it still the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting to set the `src` attr to `slide_2.jpg` after a delay of 500, correct? If it is, what you are doing is wrong. You see `.delay` works with the `fxQueue` of jQuery which is a queue of functions that is used by affects, like `fadeOut` etc., and does not affect calls like `.attr` etc., that are not related to affects/animations. So you could pass a callback function to `.fadeOut` and set the `src` attribute in that, like so

```
$("#slides1")
    .attr("src", "resources/images/slide_1.jpg")  // show slide 1
    .delay(500)  // ...for 500ms
    .fadeOut(1000, function () {  // do fade out animation for 1000ms
        $(this)
            .attr("src", "resources/images/slide_2.jpg")  // show slide 2
            .fadeIn(1000)  // ...by fading in for 1000ms
            .delay(500)  // ...for 500ms
    });
```

Not tested, but should work. Tell me if this is not what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#slides1").attr("src", "resources/images/slide_1.jpg");
            $("#slides1").fadeOut(1000 , 
                    function (){
                      $("#slides1").delay(1000).attr("src", "resources/images/slide_2.jpg");
                      $("#slides1").fadeIn(1000).delay(1000);
                 }
              );


        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the first image has loaded before executing the script, try...

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $("#slides1").attr("src", "resources/images/slide_2.jpg").fadeOut(1000).delay(1000).attr("src", "resources/images/slide_1.jpg").fadeIn(1000);
});
```

EDIT: cleaned up and corrected code

Comment: won't work. `.delay` does not delay the setting of attributes. by default, it works with `fxQueue` which means, it only delays animations

Comment: my bad, I meant to strip that out as it's not even needed due to the `.load` call

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to create this behavior successfully is to chain two setTimeouts within a recursive function call.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var images = ["resources/images/slide_1.png", "resources/images/slide_2.png"];
    var time = 1000;
    replace(0);

    function replace(counter){
        if( counter >= images.length)
            counter = 0;

        $("#slides1").attr("src",images[counter++]);
        $("#slides1").fadeIn(time);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#slides1").fadeOut(time);
            setTimeout(function(){
                replace(counter);
            }, time);
        }, time);   

    }
});
```

Comment: the image will be immediately changed to display `slide_2`. `delay` and `fadeOut` do not block. They return immediately.